# Platform-related output file location name with CMake

Tags: cmake

I have a question related to how to set the location of output file (library and executable program) with CMake. I want to compile my library and build it in 32 platform and in 64 platform respectively. For example, the output file path of the library in Windows should be:

```
/path/to/library/32/compile_option/library_name.dll
/path/to/library/64/compile_option/library_name.dll
```

depending on its platform (32/64). Now my question is how I could do that with CMake. I understand that by setting `set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH Project_OUTPUT)`we can change the output file location in CMake, but how to make the path depend on platforms is beyond my knowledge. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

CMake provides three variables to describe the system:

- CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME (Window, Linux, Darwin),
- CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR (depends on the OS, for instance i386 on Linux, x86 on Windows, etc.)
- CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION (depends on the OS too)

You could use those variables to build the output path, for instance:

```
if (${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR} STREQUAL "x86")
    set(MY_PATH_BITS "32")
else()
    set(MY_PATH_BITS "64")
endif()
```

You can make the same for compile options (as I guess they are set from CMake variables):

```
if (USE_SOME_FLAG)
    add_definitions( ... )
    set(MY_PATH_FLAGS "${MY_PATH_FLAGS}-someflag")
endif()
```

Then build the output path from those variables:

```
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH
    /path/to/library/${MY_PATH_BITS}/${MY_PATH_FLAGS}/library_name.dll)
```